# Limit of expression involving nth power

Tags: limits

[image]

But how do you evaluate it with the likes of the $16$, $+7$ and $+2$ to factor in?

Comment: Just divide both and bottom by $n^3$.  You'll have the top is zero while the bottom is a very large number as $n$ grows large.

Answer (score 1):

Hint divide by $n^2$ so we get $$\frac{16+7/n^2}{3^n/n^2+2/n^2}$$ so now can you see that as $n->\infty$ the denominator becomes large and the numerator remains as a constant. So as n approaches $\infty$ the expression goes to $0$